# Breakpoint issue with UFT 11.5

Tags: breakpoints, hp-uft

Each time I run my execution in UFT it always get paused on the breakpoints which I had put during the previous run. After selecting "clear all breakpoints" from Run menu in UFT this problem is resolved for the current run, however in the next run it again get stuck on the same breakpoints.

Its seem that breakpoints are not getting clear permanently. Is there a way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in UFT.  That entire release was pretty buggy and was almost unusable without the first service pack.  Install all the service packs (last I checked we were up to 11.53) and see if it persists.  There's also the option of upgrading to UFT 12.

Answer (score 0):

UFT 12.1 is available now try it 11.50 buggy version ! 
and the most stable release 11.53 patch.

Answer (score 0):

you can try also to install the patch 3 for the service pack 3 on UFT 11.50.

yesterday the first patch for UFT 12.01 was released.